# Why the article before "when"?

Tags: grammar

In heist comedy movie *Logan Lucky (2017)*, Jimmy wants to steal money:

> Jimmy: I even know **the when** to do it. June 4th, the Grocery Castle
> Auto Show. It's graduation weekend. It'll be the smallest turnout  of
> the summer. And gonna be bare bones staff and security.

Why the article before "when"?

Comment: The cited usage is *very* unusual / stylised (it's nowhere near "grammatical"). It's probably *slightly* modelled on the "frozen form" [***the whys and {the} wherefores***](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+whys+and+wherefores#:~:text=All%20the%20underlying%20causes%20and,how%20it%20came%20to%20be.%20%5B) (itself just an affected way of saying *the **reasons***), as well as probably referring back to some earlier conversation where *other* "aspects" of the plan were discussed. It's unlikely you'll ever encounter any other context where it would be a good idea to copy this "odd" usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, “when” is used as a countable noun to mean “date”. And we use an article before a countable noun. He has used the definite article before “when” to talk about one specific date. However, It’s informal to use “when” as a noun.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do something that involves planning, like a crime, you usually need to know three things: when, where, and how. If you are talking about these things, you will use the article to talk about them. That is why he says "the when", because he's talking about that part of the plan.